# AutoMapper bi-directional mapping between first item in collection and single property

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

I'm using AutoMapper 6. Consider the following classes:

```
public class Source
{
    public FlattenableClass Flattenable { get; set; }

    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string FlattenableProp1 { get; set; }

    public string FlattenableProp2 { get; set; }

    public MappedEmailAddress EmailAddress1 { get; set; }
}
```

where `FlattenableClass` has properties named `Prop1` and `Prop2`. As you can see, the source has a collection of `EmailAddress` but the destination only needs the first one because although our database allows a collection of email addresses, the application is going to support one. I believe I can arrange this mapping from `Source` to `Destination` like so:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(d => d.EmailAddress1, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(s => s.EmailAddresses?.FirstOrDefault()));
```

but, unsurprisingly, if I then call `ReverseMap()` on that, it doesn't know how to map `EmailAddress1` back into the `EmailAddresses` collection. Is there any way to get it to map `EmailAddress1` back to an `EmailAddress` and add it to the `EmailAddresses` collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any support in AutoMapper but I found a work around. I just created a target property in the source to do the work for me:

```
public class Destination
{
    public string FlattenableProp1 { get; set; }

    public string FlattenableProp2 { get; set; }

    public MappedEmailAddress EmailAddress1 { get; set; }

    public List<MappedEmailAddress> EmailAddresses
    {
        get
        {
            List<MappedEmailAddress> emails = new List<MappedEmailAddress>();
            if (EmailAddress1 != null) emails.Add(EmailAddress1);

            return emails;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || value.Count == 0)
                EmailAddress1 = new MappedEmailAddress();
            else
                EmailAddress1 = value[0];
        }
    }
}
```

This lets AutoMapper map `Source.EmailAddresses` to `Destination.EmailAddresses` and then `Destination.EmailAddresses` does the work of mapping to `EmailAddress1`. It's not ideal in that I had to expose collection of email addresses property which I don't want to ever be used by anyone but auto-mapper, but it gets it done.